# 'ClaimsPrincipal' does not contain a definition for 'GetUserId'

Tags: asp.net-identity, dnx

Some time ago, I created a project using the ASP.Net 5 web application template.
I recall the project built at the time.

Now when I try and build an old project I created I have the error

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'ClaimsPrincipal' does not contain a definition for 'GetUserId' 
and no extension method 'GetUserId' accepting a first argument of type 'ClaimsPrincipal' could be found
 (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  KGWebsite.DNX 4.5.1, KGWebsite.DNX Core 5.0 
E:\EShared\Dev2016\KG.Website\KGWebsite\src\KGWebsite\Controllers\Web\ManageController.cs   291 Active
```

When I create a new project from scratch using he same template, the new project will build.  I am having problems troubleshooting the difference between the two projects.

Both use DNX4.5.1 which shows in the solution explorer as having a reference to Microsoft.AspNet.Identity ( 3.0.0-rc1-final)

When I drill into the metadata for Microsoft.AspNet.Http in the working copy I have

```
#region Assembly Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
// C:\Users\kirsten\.dnx\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Abstractions\1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Abstractions.dll
#endregion
```

In the non working copy I have

```
#region Assembly Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ViewFeatures, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
// C:\Users\kirsten\.dnx\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ViewFeatures\6.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ViewFeatures.dll
#endregion
```

What steps should I be taking to correct the project that is not working?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`GetUserId()` method is a extension method which is implemented in `System.Security.Claims` namespace. So to use the method simply add the namespace in your class:

```
using System.Security.Claims;
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't find extension methods very intuitive

Comment: This has changed in RC2 - you now need to inject your `UserManager` instance and call `GetUserID(User) on it. https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/140